# cannot recognize input near in hive

Tags: hive

```
select household,COUNT(*),(COUNT(*))/(select COUNT(*) from finalcampaign) *100 as Higndecimal from finalcampaign group by household;
```

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:37 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'COUNT' '(' in expression specification

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This syntax is not supported in Hive. You can store the total count in a variable and then try to do something like: 'select household,count(\*),count(\*)/${hivevar:var1} from finalcampaign group by household;'

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with a table alias like this:

```
select household, COUNT(*), 100*(COUNT(*))/B.CNT from finalcampaign , (select COUNT(*) as CNT from finalcampaign)  As B group by household,B.CNT;
```